# How to display numerically number of displayed results based on specific input in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("BOILER MASTER DATA LIST"),
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
selectizeInput("Status", "Select a Status", choices = NULL)),

mainPanel(
tableOutput("BOILERDATA")),))

server <- function(input, output, session){(

updateSelectizeInput(session,"Status", choices = RawData$Status, server = TRUE)

output$BOILERDATA <- renderTable({statefilter <- subset(RawData, RawData$Status == input$Status, drop = TRUE)})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to add output in server part showing no. of results displayed based on input selected. Please help.

Comment: Where do you want to output number of results? How do *you* define number of results? What have you tried?

Comment: I want output to be shown below the input box. Result may be define by the no. Of rows filtered nased on inout data. I tried nrow, or count.fields. But all this is cusing errors in code.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra output, e.g. a `textOutput`, in you UI.  `renderTable` only handles tables and table-like structures. If you wanted something written beneath the table, you would literally have to append a row with the text. Ever done that in Excel? Then you know you'll also have to handle textoverflow, spanning cells, perhaps borders, etc. And it kinda breaks the idea that you have your tabular data *and* random non-tabular data, in a tabular scaffold.

Then you need to assign it some output. Ideally `nrow(statefilter)`, but you can't because it is not defined outside of the scope of your `renderTable`. Instead of preparing your data in the table, and then somehow assigning it to a variable that other scopes can find, we break the task up in two distinct parts: 1) preparing the (subsetted) data, and 2) formatting it for presentation. Currently, you are doing both in `renderTable`. Which by itself is okay, it just makes it harder to build further on. So, to do part 1 outside of `renderTable` you have to do it in a *reactive context*, because it uses a reactive variable as input (`input$Status`).

```
filtered <- reactive({
  req(length(input$Status) == 0)
  subset(RawData, RawData$Status == input$Status, drop = TRUE) 
})
output$BOILERDATA <- renderTable( filtered() )
output$rows <- renderText( nrow(filtered() )
```

Do yourself a favour and lookup what `req` does.